# Angular 8 library with CommonModule (ngif, ngfor, ngclass, etc)

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an Angular(8) library, let's call it "Foo", for an internal project at work.

```sh
ng new --create-application=false my-workspace
ng generate lib foo -p foo
```

I then create my components. Say a `bar` component.

```sh
my-workspace/projects/foo/src/lib/bar/bar.component.ts
my-workspace/projects/foo/src/lib/bar/bar.module.ts
```

bar.component.ts:

```js
@Component({                                                                                                                                               
  selector: 'foo-bar',                                                                                                                                 
  template: `                                                                                                                                              
    <div>
      <span *ngIf="show">{{ message }}</span>
    </div>  
  `                                    
})                                    
export class BarComponent {                               
  @Input() message: string                                      
  @Input() show: boolean                                                           
}
```

Since it needs to use `*ngIf`, so I add `CommonModule` to its module.

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({                                                                                                                                           
  declarations: [BarComponent],                                                
  imports: [                                                                     
    CommonModule                                                                       
  ],                                                                                  
  exports: [BarComponent],                                         
})
```

I add them both to the `public-api.ts`:

```js
export * from './lib/bar/bar.component';
export * from './lib/bar/bar.module';
```

I give it a name and version and all that in `package.json`.

It compiles too

```sh
ng build foo
[many words]
Built Angular Package!
- from: ~/code/my-workspace/foo/projects/foo
- to:   ~/code/my-workspace/foo/dist/foo
```

Great. Time to use it.

Link it up in the project needing the foo library. The usually npm package and link stuff. No biggie.

In the `app.module.ts` I import it

```js
import { BarModule } from 'foo';
// ...
imports: [
    ...,
    BarModule
]
```

If I `console.log(BarModule)` here, then I see it. If I misspell anything, then I also get errors that I'd expect. Great.

And then now I should be able to use it in my template.

```html
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
```

Everything builds. No complaints anywhere, until I hit the browser where I get this error:

```sh
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:855)
    at resolveToken (core.js:17513)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:17439)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17265)
    at resolveToken (core.js:17513)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:17439)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17265)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30392)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31577)
    at resolveDep (core.js:32142)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Something is injected and it's `null` but shouldn't be. Is that reading it correctly? If so, what? and where? Googling this turns up some hints of semi related problems. I've found that none of their solutions have solved my problem.

Some things I've tried:

- Export `CommonModule` from Foo module. At different keys, and in different orders. Nothing seems to help.
- `preserveSymlinks: true` in `angular.json`
- Removing the `*ngIf` (and `ngClass`) parts in my Foo module makes everything work

Comment: can you show us your `bar.component.html` file?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the question. -- Done

Comment: try `ng build --prod` and look if there is any error

Comment: Got an error (`Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace`) that led me to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12290

Comment: Is it running in `jit` compilation mode. If yes, it would be very easy for us if you can share a stackblitz link.

Comment: I don't know, so probably not. I'll do some digging to find out how to do that. I assume you mean `jit` compilation of the library.

Comment: According to this https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler it seems like `jit` is the default. How can I share a stackblitz link if we are talking about two separate (local) projects?

Comment: try `ng build foo --aot` then

Comment: `npx ng build foo --aot`
Unknown option: '--aot'
 .... Why would it say that? That's directly out of the docs. Or maybe that doesn't work for libraries?

Comment: Try to serve your project by `ng serve --aot`?

Comment: What the... that worked. At least my little test here worked. Why would that make a difference? ... I'll check with the real project.

Comment: The `--aot` flag breaks the project build (granted, it's a prototype project to see if Angular is something we want to use -- so it has never seen production).

Comment: Probably because you have installed the library via a local directory instead of remotely. In a real project, maybe you need to publish your library to a remote repository.

Comment: I fixed the error for my "real" project (a `private` property that should be `public`). So everything seems to work now. Thank you very much for your help! (I have spent days on this). However I still don't understand why whether it's local or remote would matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments to the question for answers. This answer is just to help future readers, and to have a way to mark the question as resolved.

To use the library that is **locally** linked, you need to use the `--aot` flag to serve the project (the user of the library).

I did a little digging.

Keep in mind that the below is only for libraries that depend on `CommonModule` (or I presume any external (Angular?) library. And only for local development. Also, contrary to what I've seen others online do in similar situations, `"preserveSymblinks": true` in `angular.json` din **not** help.

---

**Works 1**

- Do all the above
- Don't use `npm start` or `ng serve` to serve the application, but `ng serve --aot`.

**Works 2**

- Instead of using `npm link` to link the project with the library, actually copy the files to `node_modules/`.
- `npm start`

**Does not work 1** (my attempt that led to this SO question)

- Creating the library, `ng build foo`
- `npm link ../[...]/foo`
- `npm start`

**Does not work 2**

- Create library like above
- `ln -s [path to lib]/foo ./node_modules/foo`
- `npm start`

---

This may (or may not?) be related: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9273