# Angular Structural Directives is not working from NPM

Tags: angular, npm

1. I've created npm package `sezam-shareds`
2. Install package to new Project
3. Added component from this package: `<sezam-overflow [show]="true"></sezam-overflow>` to component in project
4. An error occurs in browser console: `core.js:9847 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

**Content of html in package:**

```
<div *ngIf="show">
...
</div>
```

**Content of html in project:**

```
<sezam-overflow [show]="true"></sezam-overflow>
```

**Component in package:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sezam-overflow',
  templateUrl: `sezam-overflow.component.html`,
})
export class SezamOverflowComponent {
  @Input() show = false;

  constructor() {}
}
```

***How fix error? `Can't bind to 'ngIf'`***

If you would like to install a package, you need to add postintall script to package.json:
   `"postinstall": "ngcc"`

Comment: Are you importing the `CommonModule` in your package?

Comment: @jBuchholz I didn't do it. Now added and the error has disappeared. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

this error is not related to the component.
just add the below code to your module

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

your final code like this

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule,BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [SezamOverflowComponent]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Modules have already been added. If I write components with structural directives in project, it's working. If I use my npm library: `sezam-shareds`, I get error about `ngIf`

Comment: your answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449618/angular-8-library-with-commonmodule-ngif-ngfor-ngclass-etc

Answer (score 0):

4 things to check:

1. What module declares the `SezamOverflowComponent`?
2. Does this modules `exports` contain the `SezamOverflowComponent`? (I'll just assume you called this `SezamOverflowModule`...)
3. What component are you using the `<sezam-overflow>` on? What module declares this component? (Assume XxMidule...)
4. This `XxMidule` should import the `SezamOverflowModule`